# TextBox.Text Leaking Memory in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, textbox

I have an application that does a large amount of number crunching on an array of numbers. I have it set to every 100,000 operations to display the status of those numbers. This is just sort of a visual indicator to the operator that the application is still processing, and how close it is to completed.

After running the application for several hours, it crashes with an OutOfMemoryExeption. I ran CLRProfiler on it, and found that the leak is occurring in the TextBox that shows the current state of the array... the application builds ~4K in Char[] every time the interface updates, the stack trace for each bit of hung memory is the same.

Is this a bug in WPF, or is there something that I don't know I should be doing to prevent this from happening? I've not seen any other references to this. Since this is a pretty processor intensive operation anyway, I'd prefer not to have to destroy and rebuild the TextBox if I don't have to just to display the current state of the array.

This is the only memory leak that I can find, but due to the sheer number of operations required, it's actually a big problem for the application, even if I simply reduce the frequency of the interface update. If you need more information, I'll assist if at all possible, but please understand that due to what this application does, I can't post hardly any source code, and I'll have to anonymize anything (removing any indication of the application's purpose) that I CAN post.

When run through the CLR Profiler, which DRASTICALLY reduces performance, the following identical trace occurs every 2 seconds (remember: 100,000 operations) and the memory is never deallocated. When it's running without a profiler attached, the time between updates is < 1 second.

The trace from one update ("Who Allocated") is:

```
<root> :  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
 WpfApplication0.App::Main static void ():  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
  System.Windows.Application::Run int32 ():  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
   System.Windows.Application::Run int32 (System.Windows.Window):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
    System.Windows.Application::RunInternal int32 (System.Windows.Window):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
     System.Windows.Application::RunDispatcher Object (Object):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
      System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::Run static void ():  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
       System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::PushFrame static void (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::PushFrameImpl void (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
         NATIVE FUNCTION ( UNKNOWN ARGUMENTS ):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
          MS.Win32.HwndSubclass::SubclassWndProc int_ptr (int_ptr int32 int_ptr int_ptr):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
           System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::Invoke Object (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority  Object):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::InvokeImpl Object (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority   Object bool):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
             System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::WrappedInvoke Object ( Object bool ):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
              System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper::TryCatchWhen Object (Object  Object bool ):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
               System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper::InternalRealCall Object ( Object bool):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                MS.Win32.HwndSubclass::DispatcherCallbackOperation Object (Object):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                 MS.Win32.HwndWrapper::WndProc int_ptr (int_ptr int32 int_ptr int_ptr bool&):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                  System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::WndProcHook int_ptr (int_ptr int32 int_ptr int_ptr bool&):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::ProcessQueue void ():  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation::Invoke Object ():  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                     System.Threading.ExecutionContext::Run static void (System.Threading.ExecutionContext System.Threading.ContextCallback Object):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                      System.Threading.ExecutionContext::RunInternal static void (System.Threading.ExecutionContext System.Threading.ContextCallback Object):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                       System.Threading.ExecutionContext::runTryCode static void (Object):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation::InvokeInSecurityContext static void (Object):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                         System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation::InvokeImpl void ():  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                          System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::WrappedInvoke(1) Object ( Object bool ):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                           System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper::TryCatchWhen(1) Object (Object  Object bool ):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                            System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper::InternalRealCall(1) Object ( Object bool):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                             System.Delegate::DynamicInvokeImpl Object (Object[]):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                              System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo::Invoke Object (Object System.Reflection.BindingFlags System.Reflection.Binder Object[] System.Globalization.CultureInfo bool):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                               System.RuntimeMethodHandle::InvokeMethodFast Object (Object Object[] System.Signature System.Reflection.MethodAttributes System.RuntimeTypeHandle):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                WpfApplication0.Window1::UpdateUI void ():  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                 System.Windows.Controls.TextBox::set_Text void (String):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                  System.Windows.DependencyObject::SetValue void (System.Windows.DependencyProperty Object):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                   System.Windows.DependencyObject::SetValueCommon void (System.Windows.DependencyProperty Object System.Windows.PropertyMetadata bool System.Windows.OperationType bool):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                    System.Windows.DependencyObject::UpdateEffectiveValue System.Windows.UpdateResult (System.Windows.EntryIndex System.Windows.DependencyProperty System.Windows.PropertyMetadata System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry& bool System.Windows.OperationType):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                     System.Windows.DependencyObject::NotifyPropertyChange void (System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                      System.Windows.Controls.TextBox::OnPropertyChanged void ():  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                       System.Windows.FrameworkElement::OnPropertyChanged void ():  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                        System.Windows.DependencyObject::OnPropertyChanged void (System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                         System.Windows.Controls.TextBox::OnTextPropertyChanged static void ( ):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                          System.Windows.Documents.TextContainer::DeleteContentInternal void (System.Windows.Documents.TextPointer System.Windows.Documents.TextPointer):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                           System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeUndo::CreateDeleteContentUndoUnit static System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeDeleteContentUndoUnit (System.Windows.Documents.TextContainer System.Windows.Documents.TextPointer System.Windows.Documents.TextPointer):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                            System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeDeleteContentUndoUnit::.ctor void (System.Windows.Documents.TextContainer System.Windows.Documents.TextPointer System.Windows.Documents.TextPointer):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                             System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeDeleteContentUndoUnit::CopyContent ContentContainer (System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeNode System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeNode):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                              System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeDeleteContentUndoUnit::CopyTextNode System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeNode (System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeTextNode System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeNode ContentContainer&):  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
                                               System.Char [] :  3.7 kB    (100.00%)
```

and the code generating a UI update is:

```
        List<int> arraystatus = new List<int>(displayarray.ToArray());

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        int i = 1;

        foreach (int item in arraystatus)
        {
            s.Append(i.ToString() + ":\t" + item.ToString() + (i % 8 == 0 ? "\n" : "\t"));
            i++;
        }

        txtStatus.Text = s.ToString();

        arraystatus = null;
        s = null;
```

Comment: Is it a bug in WPF?  99% sure no.  Are you allocating craptons of strings?  Could be, not sure from your code.  Is there a better way?  Probably.

Comment: Also, memory generally isn't deallocated while debugging; does this happen while running in release?

Comment: This is very literally the only bit of code that ever creates a string past the initial creation of the UI. It's encapsulated inside a method which is invoked by the dispatcher from my worker thread every 100,000 operations. Yes, it's a lot of strings. My question is "Why aren't they going away?". And yes, it happens in release or debug.

Comment: I assume this is a code inside Update(). Why do you allocate new StringBuldier every time? Also you don't need extra list since Array implements IEnumerable interface. Also you could use for your message String.Format(); since strings are immutable.

Comment: try to force GC
      GC.Collect();
      GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Comment: @lukas GC.Collect is not for you.  Not yours.  Once you start typing G and C in your code, you've already done it wrong.

Comment: I think he means use it as a test to see if it's just a case of the GC not being assertive about it.

Comment: @Yota you're much more generous than I.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the documentation of the TextBoxBase.UndoLimit property:

> The number of actions stored in the undo queue. The default is –1, which
>   means the undo queue is limited to the
>   memory that is available.

You found that limit.  Set it to a reasonably small value.

It otherwise doesn't normally make a lot of sense to display logging information in a TextBox.  It is really meant to allow the user to enter text.  Perhaps TextBlock is a better choice.

---

UPDATE: in .NET 4.5, the default of -1 was changed to 100 to avoid this kind of runaway memory usage.

Comment: Excellent catch on that... it's running smooth with no leaks now. Thanks! +1 and Accept.

Comment: * wipes up the spilt failsauce *

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Hans.

Also, you're using StringBuilder.  Awesome.

However, you're concatenating FOUR strings for every item in `arraystatus` (which could be 100k for all I know) for each time your UI is updated, making StringBuilder pretty much pointless.

Try

```
s.Append(i.ToString());
s.Append(":\t");
s.Append(item.ToString());
s.Append(i % 8 == 0 ? "\n" : "\t"));
```

or, even better, try converting this to a single call of `AppendFormat`.

Comment: Yeah, my stupidity there, wasn't thinking while I was writing apparently one day... +1