# File.ReadAllText leading to memory leak

Tags: c#, delegates, garbage-collection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TextBox.Text Leaking Memory in WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336908/textbox-text-leaking-memory-in-wpf-application)

I've got an application trailing a logfile. Every time the logfile updates (which is usually a series of updates in a row) the memory use balloons out of control.

I've tracked down the problem to this call:

```
    if (File.Exists(Path + "\\logfile.txt"))
                Data = File.ReadAllText(Path + "\\logfile.txt");
```

This is being called from within LoadAllData, here.

```
    private void FileChangeNotificationHandler(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
          (new Action(delegate()
          {
              Logfile.GetPath();
              Logfile.LoadAllData();

              LogText.Clear();
              LogText.Text = Logfile.Data;
              if (CheckFollowTail.IsChecked == true) LogText.ScrollToEnd();
          }));
    }
```

Does anyone have insight on why this occurring? I assume it's related to the delegate or the handler.

Comment: So, every time your logfile changes, you throw away all of the content and completely reload the file?

Comment: I ruled out the textbox assignment being the problem.

Comment: Right, the logfile is small enough. I'll give it more intelligence when it becomes necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably just down to the amount and frequency with which you are loading log file data into memory.

GC takes time, so it you are repeating this in quick succession, then chances are you'll have several files worth of data in memory until the next GC. This seems very inefficient. You should consider the use of a [stream based reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx), to avoid keeping all the data in memory. If you do use a stream reader, make sure you `dispose` of it afterwards to avoid introducing another leak.

The another thing to check it that your not subscribing to a static event somewhere and therefore preventing your object tree from being disposed. Is it a web app?

Comment: Some LOH fragmentation could be going on as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a desktop app, WPF. I'll try the stream reader and see what happens.

Comment: Make sure you dispose of the stream reader, otherwise you'll have another leak.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, checking if the file exists is wrong. This is because the file system is *volatile* and because there is more than just existence at play (permissions, for example).  The correct way to do this is to *just open the file*, and then handle the exception if it fails.

Now, on to your stated problem.  What I suspect is happening is that the log is growing large enough to use the Large Object Heap (85000 bytes is all that's needed, iirc, and remember that .Net uses utf16 (2-byte) characters).  A 43K ascii log file is all you'll need to start causing problems, because at that size your .Net string is no longer garbage collected in the normal way. Every time you read the file you end up adding another instance of the entire log file to memory.

To best recommend how to get around this, it will be helpful to know what kind of component you use for your `LogText` variable.  But pending that information, I can at least suggest a few pointers:

Ideally, you would just keep the file open (using [FileShare.ReadWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx)) and read from the stream every time you get a change notification.  But that's not always possible.

If you have to re-open the file each time, at least read the text line by line (using a StreamReader) rather than pulling it all at once using File.ReadAllLines(). This will help you keep your log file broken up into smaller pieces that won't end up on the large object heap.

Unfortunately, I suspect that in the end you're stuck building one big string to assign to a plain textbox.  If this is the case, I **strongly** recommend that you either only ever build and show the last part of the log (less than 85000 bytes worth) or that you search for a Large Object Heap-safe Textbox component to use.

Comment: +1.  For further reading:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/12/10/the-file-system-is-unpredictable.aspx

Comment: I disagree that checking file exists is wrong. You should always code defensively to avoid exceptions, they are expensive. Yes file system is volatile, and exceptions can still occur but in this case it's more likely to be the edge case. Using exceptions to control flow is wrong.

Comment: @TheCodeKing:  MSFT Employees suggest otherwise... See my previous commment.

Comment: @TheCode - it's not just deletions at stake, but permission (the file may exist, but you don't have rights to read from it) and sharing (you might have permissions, but it's locked because someone else has it open). This particular question is a **perfect example** of the latter, as there are a lot of log writers out there that will lock their log file while they write to it, and the writes are arleady known to come in batches. Since you need to have a good exception handler anyway, the File.Exists check is wasteful and leads to a false sense of security.

Comment: Yeah not convinced at all. File.Exists only returns true if you have permissions to access the file. I'd agree there are cases there it could be an advantage.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. The logfile was actually only kilobytes large - it was ballooning about 5 megs per kilobyte! I removed the File.Exists check, since the function does handle IOExceptions. I removed it to keep the code simple.